# javascript e jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> A. Altere a implementação do evento click aplicado aos itens da lista,
>   para permitir alternar os itens "riscados", ou seja, se um item não
>   estiver marcado, aplica-se o estilo para marcar. Se já estiver
>   marcado, retira-se este estilo, para que ele volte ao normal.
>
> B. Crie um novo botão no HTML, com o texto "Limpar Concluídos".
>   Programe o evento click deste botão para remover todos itens da lista
>   que estiverem "riscados" por já terem sido marcados anteriormente pelo
>   usuário, não afetando os demais itens.
>
> C. Programe um evento de duplo-clique (dblclick) para os itens da
>   lista. O item que for acionado com um duplo-click deve ser removido
>   permanentemente da lista. Não modifique a funcionalidade de click,
>   apenas crie um novo evento independente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Exercício 01</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lista de Tarefas</h1>

  <input id="texto" placeholder="O que precisa ser feito?">
  <button id="adicionar">Adicionar</button>
  <button id="limparTudo">Limpar Tudo</button>

  <ul id="lista"></ul>

  <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('#limparTudo').hide()

  $('#adicionar').click(() => {
    const valor = $('#texto').focus().val()

    if (valor) {
      $('#limparTudo').show()

      $('#texto').val('')

      $('<li>')
        .text(valor)
        .appendTo('#lista')
        .click(() => $(event.target).css('text-decoration', 'line-through'))
    }
  })

  $('#texto').focus().keyup(() => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) $('#adicionar').click()
  })

  $('#limparTudo').click(() => {
    $('#lista li').remove()
    $('#limparTudo').hide()
    $('#texto').val('').focus()
  })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Alguém consegue fazer para mim não estou entendendo ou pelo menos mandar que tipo de codigo usa cada exercicio.

Comment: Sua a dúvida é em qual dos exercicios? poderia dar mais detalhes de qual parte tem dificuldades.

Comment: no exercicio A 
como eu faço para selecionar o texto

Answer (score 0):

Abaixo um exemplo com as três solicitações funcionando.

Basta executar e testar.

```js
$('#limparConcluidos').hide() // oculta o botão Limpar Concluídos
$('#limparTudo').hide()

  $('#adicionar').click(() => {
    const valor = $('#texto').focus().val()
    if (valor) {
      $('#limparConcluidos').show() // exibe o botão Limpar Concluídos
      $('#limparTudo').show()
      $('#texto').val('')
      $('<li>')
        .text(valor)
        .appendTo('#lista')
        .click(() => $(event.target).toggleClass('riscado')) // acrescenta ou remove a classe riscado
        .dblclick(() => $(event.target).remove()) // se der duplo clique, remove
    }
  })

  $('#texto').focus().keyup(() => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) $('#adicionar').click()
  })

  $('#limparTudo').click(() => {
    $('#lista li').remove();
    $('#limparConcluidos').hide(); // oculta o botão Limpar Concluídos
    $('#limparTudo').hide();
    $('#texto').val('').focus();
  })
  
  
 // se clicar no botão limpar concluidos, remove todos os riscados 
 $('#limparConcluidos').click(() => {
     $('#lista li.riscado').remove();
 })
```

```css
.riscado{
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Exercício 01</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lista de Tarefas</h1>
  <input id="texto" placeholder="O que precisa ser feito?">
  <button id="adicionar">Adicionar</button>
  <button id="limparConcluidos">Limpar Concluídos</button>
  <button id="limparTudo">Limpar Tudo</button>

  <ul id="lista"></ul>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deu certo o código acima?